# Which Installler does elementary OS use?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

Ubuntu uses Ubiquity installer to install the OS to a system. Since elementary OS is an ubuntu derivative, which installer does elementary OS uses?

The installer that elementary OS uses is stripped down version of Ubiquity as it seemed to me. But I was not able to find the code for what is elementary OS removing from Ubiquity. 
I took a look at 
*https://code.launchpad.net/elementary/+branches?*
But I was not able to find where elementary is modifying Ubiquity.

Any links will be very helpful. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

elementary OS uses a forked version Ubiquity which changes branding to elementary OS instead of Ubuntu.The source code should be able on LaunchPad but I could not find it.

You can see that elementary OS uses Ubiquity by typing `ubiquity` in a terminal while running from a live USB / CD. This will open the elementary OS installer.

EDIT : Daniel Foré commented that the patch for Ubiquity is location on LaunchPad @ https://code.launchpad.net/~elementary-os/elementaryos/os-patch-ubiquity-xenial (this is for Xenial)

Comment: Is its source available somewhere online? I can get the source using apt-get source ubiquity though. But there should be an online resource somewhere.

Comment: Try a Google search for `elementary OS Ubiquity`. I got some LaunchPad results but I do not know if they are the correct repositories

Comment: It's not entirely a fork. We carry distro patches. The latest patch set is at https://code.launchpad.net/~elementary-os/elementaryos/os-patch-ubiquity-xenial. The patch set for Freya is at https://code.launchpad.net/~elementary-os/elementaryos/os-patch-ubiquity-trusty